# Stokes theorem, intersection between cylinder and plane

Tags: vector-analysis, stokes-theorem

[image]

$\mathcal C$ is the intersection curve between the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 2y$ and the plane $y = z$. I tried parameterizing the curve by expanding the cylinder equation $x^2 + (y-1)^2 = 1$. I think I can write the parameterization as follows: $(r \cos(\theta), r \sin(\theta) + 1, 0)$? How do I proceed from here, I want to use Stokes theorem. $\mathcal C$ is oriented counterclockwise.

Comment: You’ve parameterized the projection of the cylinder onto the $x$-$y$ plane. Now use $y=z$ to get the correct curve.

Comment: @StudentMaths Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

We have

- $F=(y^2,xy,xz)\implies \operatorname{rot}(F)=(0,-z,-y)$

then

$$\int_C y^2\,dx+xy\,dy+xz\,dz =\int_S \operatorname{rot}(F)\cdot n \,dS$$

and

$$\operatorname{rot}(F)\cdot n=(0,z,-y)\cdot (0,-1/\sqrt 2,1/\sqrt 2)=\frac z {\sqrt 2}-\frac y {\sqrt 2}$$

Comment: How do you find the normal vector? And should'nt it be rot(F) = (0, -z, -y) ?

Comment: @StudentMaths Ops...you are right it is rot(F) = (0, -z, -y) of course. For the normal recall that for a plane ax+by+cz+d=0 the normal n=(a,b,c).

Comment: Thank you! I get this 1/sqrt(2) * integral 4y dxdy but what are the boundaries? I feel this would be easier to solve with polar coordinates.

Comment: Since y=z I suppose rot(F)=0.

Answer (score 0):

Take $S$ to be the region in the plane $y = z$ enclosed by $\mathcal C$. Since $\nabla \times \mathbf F = (0, -z, -y)$ is parallel to the plane $y = z$, $(\nabla \times \mathbf F) \cdot d\mathbf S = 0$.